# Livewire modal window with readonly inputs

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I'm using Jetstream blade components in my project, including x-jet-dialog-modal and x-jet-input. The modal window is used to add or edit records and works fine. The inputs are bound to a model "person" using the "wire:" syntax, and everything goes as expected.
Now I want to use the same modal window to show the record fields in a read-only manner, when pressing a "view" button. My idea is to make the inputs read only and hide the "save" button dynamically, using a public property of the Livewire controller (component).

So, in Livewire component I have a default value:

```
public $disableEdition = false;
```

And in the blade file:

```
<div class="mt-2">
       <x-jet-label for="name" value="{{ __('Name') }}" />
       <x-jet-input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" wire:model.defer="person.name" {{ $this->disableEdition ? 'readonly' : '' }}/>
       <x-jet-input-error for="person.name" class="mt-2" />
</div>
```

I expected the input field to appear with attribute "readonly" (and of course non-editable and formatted with corresponding Bootstrap styles), but the browser inspector reveals that no attribute was added to the input.

Maybe you can help me with a solution or even a better approach to accomplish my goal.

Best regards.

Comment: just check the public property like {{ $disableEdition ? 'readonly' : '' }}

Comment: That works, Prospero. However, the HTML attribute renders as: readonly="". The browser doesn't care about that assignation, but I wonder if it can be fixed.